# ecmascript6 spread operator is not working as expected for javascript objects

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I want to use javascript `spread` operator and I want the result of two different objects to merged using spread operator but it is not working as expected.

For instance, every time, for new request new data is coming and I want to append it a single object. For better consider, consider simple scenario:

```
const obj1 = {
    WellSchema: {
      well: [
        {wellName: 'check1', uwi: '9000000123'},
        {wellName: 'check2', uwi: '8000012432'}
      ]
    }
  }

const obj2 = {
    WellSchema: {
      well: [
        {wellName: 'check3', uwi: '2113120002'},
        {wellName: 'check4', uwi: '5679001211'},
        {wellName: 'check5', uwi: '0987652221'},
        {wellName: 'check6', uwi: '5345676542'}
      ]
    }
  }

const mutateIt = { ...obj1, ...obj2 }
console.log(mutateIt)
```

The result I am getting is below:

```
{
    WellSchema: {
      well: [
        {wellName: 'check3', uwi: '2113120002'},
        {wellName: 'check4', uwi: '5679001211'},
        {wellName: 'check5', uwi: '0987652221'},
        {wellName: 'check6', uwi: '5345676542'}
      ]
    }
  }
```

Anyhow, **intended result** should be as:

```
{
        WellSchema: {
          well: [
            {wellName: 'check1', uwi: '9000000123'},
            {wellName: 'check2', uwi: '8000012432'}
            {wellName: 'check3', uwi: '2113120002'},
            {wellName: 'check4', uwi: '5679001211'},
            {wellName: 'check5', uwi: '0987652221'},
            {wellName: 'check6', uwi: '5345676542'}
          ]
        }
      }
```

Can you suggest, what is wrong in this case? Thanks

Comment: There's nothing wrong, that's what's supposed to happen. The spread operator doesn't magically give you a deep merge, so `WellSchema` from `obj2` just overwrites `WellSchema` from `obj1`.

Comment: What you want can be easily achieved by `array#concat`.

Comment: I can't in this case. I am liable to use spread operator as everything is coming dynamically.

Comment: Just use `const mutateIt = [ ...obj1.WellSchema.well, ...obj2.WellSchema.well ];` and you will get what you want